# Image Preview using File API for images over 100MB will freeze broswer

Tags: javascript, performance, image-processing, filereader

First, let me note that I've searched and read I think all of SE questions regarding this issue and there isn't so far a good answer! (with a working example)

So, here is what I'm trying to achieve: a user selects an image in browser and using filereader I'll generate a preview before uploading. The problem is with large files, over 50MB or 100MB images which freeze the broswer

I've been trying dozens of solutions but all seem to freeze the UI of the browser. In order to generate a good quality preview, I'm using filereader and canvas with some interpolation to scale down the image.

What I noticed is that the freeze happens when the scale down and interpolation happens and during `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` call

Is there a way to avoid this (maybe using web workers?) from happening? As I said, I tried some libraries and read most of the stack questions but the ones that relate to this problem do not have an answer.

I've come across these two issues:

- the `readAsDataURL` will return a base64 encoded and extremely long
     line for over 50MB/100MB images (the base64 is 137% larger than the file
     size so this is kept in system memory) - so this might be a performance issue
- when loading a large image from `canvas.toDataURL()`, the whole page freezes while the image is being loaded

If there is someone who did this and works well and can provide some examples and explain, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla gives an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) how to use readAsDataURL. I try with a 50MB image and works perfectly ( for creating the image i use ImageJ 10000*10000 pixel random value RGB ). I think toDataURL() function create a very long String which become unreadable by the browser.

Comment: the example is good for Chrome. On Safari and Firefox, it still hangs for a couple of seconds for a 44MB image that I tried. Also, I need to do the canvas since I want to scale down the image that the user is selecting and still keep a good quality of the image.